# 'ER_PARSE_ERROR' You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql, express

I created in my model the const getbypage:

```
   const getByPage = (page = 1, limit = 10) => {
       return executeQuery(
           'select * from clientes limit ? offset = ?',
           [limit, (page-1) * limit]
       );
   }
```

in the controller:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const clients = await getByPage();
        res.render('clients/list', { arrClients: clients });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

and the error is:

code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064,
sqlState: '42000',
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to  your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 0' at line 1",
sql: 'select * from clientes limit 10 offset = 0'
}
GET /clients - - ms - -

CAN SOMEBODY HELP ME?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `=` sign from the offset part?

Comment: *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 0' at line 1* - Here is a resource to check into: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html shows you the reference documentation for the `LIMIT` clause:

```
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

There's no `=` in the syntax. You should just use `OFFSET ?`.

WRONG:

```
select * from clientes limit ? offset = ?
```

RIGHT:

```
select * from clientes limit ? offset ?
```